# Instagram doesn't use jwt on it's authentication

Tags: authentication, token, jwt

It seems that instagram doesn't use `jwt` (Json web token) in it's authentication system.

As you know `jwt` is a more secure way for user authentication instead of session based systems. In `jwt` token is stored in the database and **with each request**, we send the token in our `localStorage` to serve to validate that. So if you logout from one account (for ex in chrome) you must be logged out in other platform (such as android app or etc).

**But in instagram** this doesn't happen. Is this mean that instagram doesn't use token based authentication?? Or maybe I can't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tokens can be classified into two categories:

- Token by reference: the token is just a (random) string and associated data are stored in a database
- Token by value: the token itself contains all the data. The token is digitally signed and may be encrypted for confidentiality.

JWT belongs to the that second category. The may advantages are that they avoid database calls and there is no cleanup to perform as they have a short lifetime.

Nevertheless, it is not true to say that JWT are more secured than other tokens.
When a token is exchanged between a server and a client, the main security hole comes from the transmission of that token when it is issued or for each request, but not from the token itself.

> So if you logout from one account (for ex in chrome) you must be logged out in other platform (such as android app or etc).

This kind of feature mainly depends on the server policy.
For example when a user logout from a browser, he may need to be logged in its app.

If you want that a user is logged out on every clients, then the server has to provide a session management with a logout system such as those described by the OpenID Connect specifications

- http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-session-1_0.html
- http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-backchannel-1_0.html
- http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-frontchannel-1_0.html

Comment: Nice description. Thanks a lot :) But again I didn't get my answer. When we logout, the token will be deleted from database, but we still can be logged in , in an other device.

Comment: I updated my answer by adding a new section related to the logout question.

Comment: Ah, yes. The main idea like telegram. You can destroy each session related to specific platform. Thank you so much.